# ReactJS: Call the state fetch the data inside of bracket array

Tags: reactjs

I start working on ReactJS Bootstrap Data table.

**Problem:**
How to fetch the api result to the data column.

**Goal:** To loop the value of response in every column in the data table.

**JSX:**

```
<Table style={{

}}
tableStyle="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-borderless table-responsive"
pages={true}
pagination={true}
onRowClick={() => {}} // if You Want Table Row Data OnClick then assign this {row => console.log(row)}
page={true}
errormsg="Error. . ."
loadingmsg="Empty Data"
isLoading={false} 
sort={true} 
search={true}
size={10}
data={{
    head: {
        id: "ID",
        name: "Name",
        email: "Email",
        created_at: "Created At",
        orders: "Orders",
        last_order: "Last OrderResponse",
        total_spent: "Total Spent"
    },
    data: [
        {
            loop will happen here!!
        }
    ]
    }}

/>
```

Comment: which package did you used? can you create stackblitz for this?

Comment: hi @Justcode i used this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-data-table

Comment: You need to show your efforts probably create a demo